# Jquery Mobile Performance?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery, event-bubbling

Please find 2 set of code blocks below and let me know which one is to follow and why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Set 1</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/customStyle.css" />    
</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role="page">      
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></div>

</div>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/customScript.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>   

</body>
</html>
```

and set 2 is....

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>Set 1</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/customStyle.css" />        

        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/customScript.js"></script>  
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
    </head>
```

(ie) which one is right, putting all the scripts at the top or at bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct, only difference is how are you going to bind events.

In the first case, because HTML is already loaded into the DOM events can be bound directly like this:

```
$('#buttonID').on('click', function(){       

});
```

Because button is already into the DOM, click event can be bound directly to it.

In the second case, because jQuery Mobile is loaded before page content all event binding must be done like delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttonID',function(){       

});
```

This is a safer but slower solution. It don't require for object to exist to bind an event to it.

To make a story short, solution 1 is slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

First case to improve performance .... this is said to be general practise to keep javascript down the page ...so that content is loaded faster .... though no facts or analysis personally I have on same.   Check this nice post sameelegantcode.com/2010/03/30/your-javascript-goes-where/

Comment: Thanks for reply!... So, we need to put all the scripts in header section only to improve perfomance - right?

Comment: First case ...sorry for extreme mistake ...and yes check the link provided ...keep js down ... there is no as such restricton on where to put ..it should be down to increase performance

Answer (score 0):

It will good to place all javascript at the bottom of the page. Never forget that page rendering can be delayed by javascript parsing/execution. Well, I believe you love to read http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom